# Deploy JavaFX stand alone with a Preloader

Tags: deployment, javafx-2, javafx

I have create a JavaFX application which includes derby.jar  for a database and Jasper Reports for generating reports which means I have also included 35+ jar files required for generattion of the reports and I have also used a preloader class to animate the loading process. I decided to use a custom deploy ant task to produce an installer. Below is the deploy ant task

```
<target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
        <fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}"
                    nativeBundles="image"
                    outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" 
                    outfile="${application.title}">
            <fx:application name="${application.title}" 
                            mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"
                            preloaderClass="transconnect.system.preloader.Splash"
                            version="1.1"/>
            <fx:resources>
                <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
                <fx:fileset id="preloader-files"
                            requiredFor="preloader"
                            dir="dist"
                            includes="lib/TransConnect System Preloader.jar"/>
               <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="lib/*.jar"/>
            </fx:resources>
        <fx:info title="${application.title}"
                vendor="${application.vendor}"
                description="A Car Rental System"/>
        <fx:preferences shortcut="true"
                        menu="true"/>
    </fx:deploy>
</target>
```

But every time i run the produce jar file I get an error that preloader class not found
[image: error]